# Attaching an Href to a row inside a table

Tags: html

I am using html in a .php file to code. I have a statement:

```
<html>

   <tr>

      <td>Hi<td>
      <td>Test<td.

   </tr>


</html>
```

How can I attach an href to the row? Simply adding href in the  tag didn't work. Anybody know how? Note: The table was defined earlier in the code this is the snip-it portion of the row.

Answer (score 0):

You do not attach href to row instead you better do as

```
  <table class="table table-stripped">
     <tr class="selectedRow">
       <td><a href="#">Hi</a></td>
      <td>Test</td>
     </tr>
  </table>
```

then using jquery :

```
$('.selectedRow').click(function(){
  alert('do something');
});
```

View [LiveWeave](http://liveweave.com/ic7Lym)